# Unhandled promise rejection warning in ionic 3

Tags: cordova, ionic3, command-line-interface

I am trying to build and run an ionic project on device but this is giving an unhandled promise rejection error, I dont know whats actually the reason, Please help friends. Please refer the image attached showing the error that I receive every time when use command "ionic cordova build android" to build my ionic project in ionic CLI 3.0.  [image]

I think, error is because the ANDROID_HOME path is not set, Please let me know how to resolve the issue. [image]

Comment: Searching alot I reached amid of the solution, where i can only able to build the the app with the help of setting the path and environment variables for java JDK 1.8, Still struggling to run the app on device, this time error is INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE when I try to install compiled .apk on device

Answer (score 0):

Are trying to dismiss any modal like this.viewctrl.dismiss? If nothing is pushed in stack and try to pop any modal state, I faced this issue.

Comment: Thanks Pradnya, But the error is something else its not related to dismissing modal, actually the project is not starting over device, it is working well with the command 'ionic serve', but doesn't building and running with the command 'ionic cordova build android'.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like problem was initially due to lower JDK version.

Now please uninstall app and try installing it again.

Comment: I have added the required jdk version 1.8, also the problem is same if I am trying to build new application.